# PHP variable is not an mysqli object

Tags: php, class, variables, object, mysqli

I have the next code (compilated in NetBeans)

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO grupos(nombre, descripcion)'
            . ' VALUES ("' . utf8_decode($_POST['name']) . '", "' . utf8_decode($_POST['desc']) . '")';
    $result = $con->query($query) or exit("Error: " . $con->errno . ": " . $con->error);
    if ($result->affected_rows > 0) {
```

Why I got this: "Trying to get property of non-object "
if when I made a echo $result; display a '1'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`mysqli::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Since your query is `INSERT`, not `SELECT`, it doesn't return a `mysqli_result`, it just returns `TRUE`. You should use `$con->affected_rows` instead of `$result->affected_rows`.

Comment: So only in the first cases I should to use $result = $con->($query)...? Or there's another better way?

Comment: Right, you don't need to assign the value to a variable when you're doing an `UPDATE` or `INSERT`. The value is either true or false depending on whether there was an error, and you're already testing for that with `or exit`.

Comment: BTW, we usually use `die()` rather than `exit()` in cases like this, so it sends an error code.

Comment: What's the difference between `die()` and `exit()`?

Comment: Oops, actually there's no difference. I guess it's just a convention, so the reader can tell that this is an error situation.